# Refresh page with PartialView that was loaded the last time

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, partial-views, razor-pages

I am using `ASP.NET Core`.
in one of my page I have a `div` that different `PartialView` can be loaded into that

```
<html>
<body style="background:url('/images/bg.png')">
    <div class="text-center">
        <div class="container" style="overflow-x:auto; background-color:white">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Patients" onclick="LoadPartial('recipe')" />
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Orders" onclick="LoadPartial('orders')" />
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Delivered" onclick="LoadPartial('deliveries')" />
            <div id="mypage">
                <partial name="RecipeList.cshtml" />
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <script>
        function LoadPartial(type) {
            var url = '@Url.Action("Recipes", "Glasses")';
            if (type == 'recipe')
                url = '@Url.Action("Recipes", "Glasses")';
            if (type == 'orders')
                url = '@Url.Action("Orders", "Glasses")';
            if (type == 'deliveries')
                url = '@Url.Action("Deliveries", "Glasses")';

            $('#mypage').load(url);
        }

        </script>
</body>
```

when user open this page for first time ,it should load the `partialview` , like the first button get clicked.

when another `partialview` get loaded and I clicked refresh button on the browser, I want to refresh a `partiaview` that was loaded not the first one.

how can I do these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the url in localStorage when you click the button, and get the value from it in $(document).ready() function then load the partial view.

```
<body>
    <div class="text-center">
        <div class="container" style="overflow-x:auto; background-color:white">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Patients" onclick="LoadPartial('recipe')" />
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Orders" onclick="LoadPartial('orders')" />
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Delivered" onclick="LoadPartial('deliveries')" />
            <div id="mypage">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

@section scripts{ 
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var url = localStorage.getItem('url');
            $('#mypage').load(url);
        })


        function LoadPartial(type) {
            var url = '@Url.Action("Recipes", "Home")';
            if (type == 'recipe')
                url = '@Url.Action("Recipes", "Home")';
            if (type == 'orders')
                url = '@Url.Action("Orders", "Home")';
            if (type == 'deliveries')
                url = '@Url.Action("Deliveries", "Home")';
            localStorage.setItem('url', url);
            $('#mypage').load(url);
        }

    </script>
}
```

Result:

[image]

**Update:**

Use sessionStorage:

```
<body>
    <div class="text-center">
        <div class="container" style="overflow-x:auto; background-color:white">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Patients" onclick="LoadPartial('recipe')" />
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Orders" onclick="LoadPartial('orders')" />
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Delivered" onclick="LoadPartial('deliveries')" />
            <div id="mypage">
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

@section scripts{ 
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var orignalurl = '@Url.Action("Recipes", "Home")';
            var url = sessionStorage.getItem('url');
            if(url != null)
                $('#mypage').load(url);
            else
                $('#mypage').load(orignalurl);
        })


        function LoadPartial(type) {
            var url = '@Url.Action("Recipes", "Home")';
            if (type == 'recipe')
                url = '@Url.Action("Recipes", "Home")';
            if (type == 'orders')
                url = '@Url.Action("Orders", "Home")';
            if (type == 'deliveries')
                url = '@Url.Action("Deliveries", "Home")';
            sessionStorage.setItem('url', url);
            $('#mypage').load(url);
        }

    </script>
}
```

Comment: thank you, but when the user open the page it should load the first one and not the last one in local storage

Comment: Do you mean when user first time come to this page it should load the orignal partialview? What about using [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage#:~:text=sessionStorage%20is%20similar%20to%20localStorage,over%20page%20reloads%20and%20restores.)

Comment: So, have you tried `sessionStorage` I mentioned above?

Comment: NO, unfortunately I don't know how to use it , you mean instead of localStorage? can you explain more?

Comment: Yeah, just replace `localStorage` with `sessionStorage`, see my update, also take a look at his [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage#:~:text=sessionStorage%20is%20similar%20to%20localStorage,over%20page%20reloads%20and%20restores.)